# Align number in tabular on the same line with its macro

Tags: tables, macros, vertical-alignment

I have this example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcount\mynote
\def\note#1{\global\mynote=#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}c}
Text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  
text  text  text  text  
text here$\rightarrow$ \note{3}  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  
text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text 
text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text 
&   
\number\mynote  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My hope is to align the number on the right side with the line which contain  `\note` macro (the method must be valid even inside enumerate environment).

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

for this is needed manual tweaking (counting lines where is `$\rightarrow$ \note{3}`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcount\mynote
\def\note#1{\global\mynote=#1\relax}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}c}
Text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
text  text  text  text  text  here  $\rightarrow$ \note{3}  text  text  text
text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
text  text
    &   \multirow[b]{3}{*}{\number\mynote}  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better if there a way to put the number  automatically, with `multirow` you need to specify  the position of  `note`  macro every time

Comment: @SalimBou, of course it would be better, but this is in table to my knowledge impossible to achieve (in normal text is possible with `\marginpar`).

Answer (score 1):

You can save the `x` and `y` coordinate of where you want it by placing markers ("label"s using [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module) and then place the content *absolutely* using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} c }
  Text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  
  text  text  text  text  
  text here $\rightarrow$ \zsaveposy{mynote-y}  text  text  text  text  text  
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text 
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text 
  &
  \zsaveposx{mynote-x}
\end{tabular}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{\zposx{mynote-x}sp}%
    \raisebox{\zposy{mynote-y}sp}{3}%
  }
}

\end{document}
```